# How to check TLS version for sender mail?

Tags: mailgun

I got mailed from MailGun that **TLS Version 1.0 and 1.1 Deprecation**. I tried to connect MailGun support team to check whether we are using any deprecated version for sender mail. Can anyone tell me that how to check TLS version for sender mail?

Comment: Are you using Java to send email ?

Comment: Java 6 + supports TLS 1.2. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#SSLContext

Comment: We are using SMTP to send mail, not Java like. Bro